# model.matrix for full model

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lm, model.matrix

I'm modeling "*full linear model*" (main effects, interactions of the second order and quadratic terms) in `R` but wondering on how to create all of these possible combinations in the simplest way, e.g., by `model.matrix`. For example, model with main effects and all possible interactions of the second order can be done such as

```
M1<-matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6)
colnames(M1)<-LETTERS[1:6]

X<-as.data.frame(M1[,1:5])
Y<-M1[,6]

f <- as.formula( ~ .^2)
MM<-model.matrix(f, X)[,-1]

lin_model<-lm(Y ~ MM)
```

Is there any simple way how to adjust `f` formula in the code above to be able to add quadratic terms into formula? E.g. if I have >10 feature I'd like to avoid explicit way of doing that.

Comment: Dont create anything. Just run the model, R will create them for you: `lm(Y~poly(as.matrix(X), 2, raw = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering how to adjust ```as.formula( ~ .^2)``` to add these quadratic terms.

Comment: You do not need to adjust anything. I just gave you the code. Use `poly`

Comment: I tried and the output is very confusing. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Ohh, the output shows the coefficients. eg when `1.0.0` it means the linear term of the 1st covariate , when 2.0.0, means quadratic term of the 1st covariate, then 1.1.0 means interaction between 1st covariate and 2nd covariate etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this.

```
set.seed(42)
M1 <- matrix(rnorm(36), ncol=6, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:6]))

X <- as.data.frame(M1[,1:5])
Y <- M1[,6]

(f <- as.formula(paste0(' ~ .^2 + ', paste(sapply(colnames(M1)[-6], \(x) paste0('I(', x, '^2)')), collapse=' + '))))
# ~.^2 + I(A^2) + I(B^2) + I(C^2) + I(D^2) + I(E^2)

(MM <- model.matrix(f, X)[,-1])
#            A          B          C          D           E     I(A^2)     I(B^2)     I(C^2)    I(D^2)      I(E^2)         A:B
# 1  1.3709584  1.51152200 -1.3888607 -2.4404669  1.8951935 1.87952706 2.284698749 1.92893405 5.95587883 3.59175826  2.07223385
# 2 -0.5646982 -0.09465904 -0.2787888  1.3201133 -0.4304691 0.31888402 0.008960334 0.07772318 1.74269925 0.18530367  0.05345379
# 3  0.3631284  2.01842371 -0.1333213 -0.3066386 -0.2572694 0.13186224 4.074034289 0.01777458 0.09402723 0.06618754  0.73294700
# 4  0.6328626 -0.06271410  0.6359504 -1.7813084 -1.7631631 0.40051508 0.003933058 0.40443291 3.17305974 3.10874406 -0.03968941
# 5  0.4042683  1.30486965 -0.2842529 -0.1719174  0.4600974 0.16343288 1.702684815 0.08079972 0.02955558 0.21168958  0.52751747
# 6 -0.1061245  2.28664539 -2.6564554  1.2146747 -0.6399949 0.01126241 5.228747152 7.05675540 1.47543462 0.40959344 -0.24266914#           A:C        A:D         A:E        B:C        B:D         B:E         C:D         C:E         D:E
#           A:C         A:D         A:E         B:C        B:D         B:E         C:D        C:E         D:E
# 1 -1.90407031 -3.34577875  2.59823148 -2.09929350 -3.6888194  2.86462661  3.38946861 -2.6321597 -4.62515697
# 2  0.15743151 -0.74546559  0.24308513  0.02638988 -0.1249607  0.04074779 -0.36803277  0.1200100 -0.56826805
# 3 -0.04841277 -0.11134919 -0.09342182 -0.26909895 -0.6189266 -0.51927862  0.04088147  0.0342995  0.07888872
# 4  0.40246923 -1.12732350 -1.11583998 -0.03988306  0.1117132  0.11057518 -1.13282381 -1.1212843  3.14073727
# 5 -0.11491445 -0.06950074  0.18600279 -0.37091301 -0.2243297  0.60036708  0.04886801 -0.1307840 -0.07909872
# 6  0.28191505 -0.12890676  0.06791915 -6.07437155  2.7775303 -1.46344133 -3.22672919  1.7001179 -0.77738558
```

This might look more appealing, but as noted by *@onyambu* actually it's the same what you get with `poly`.

```
PM <- poly(as.matrix(X), degree=2, raw=TRUE)


## show column key of PM, corresponding to MM
colnames(MM)[match(PM[1, ], MM[1, ])]
# [1] "A"      "I(A^2)" "B"      "A:B"    "I(B^2)" "C"      "A:C"    "B:C"    "I(C^2)" "D"      "A:D"   
# [12] "B:D"    "C:D"    "I(D^2)" "E"      "A:E"    "B:E"    "C:E"    "D:E"    "I(E^2)"
```

Comment: Why not use `poly(as.matrix(X), degree = 2, raw = TRUE)`?

Comment: @onyambu Have you checked `dim(poly(as.matrix(M1[, -1]), 2, raw = TRUE))`?

Comment: The `poly` drops aliases. eg with 6 datapoints, you can only estimate a maximum of 6 parameters. eg try your code with 50 datapoints

Comment: Hope you were able to confirm that `poly` is sufficient

Comment: @onyambu Just edited! That was confusing because OP used response on RHS, now dims match. Thanks very much for your help!